# How to find the second minimum number without using arrays or loops

Tags: c++

I tried to write a program that receive from the user `5` integers and print the second minimum number. 
Here is a sample of what I've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
int a,b,c,d,e;
cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;
if (a>b && a<c && a<d && a<e)
    cout<<a<<endl;
if (b>a && b<c && b<d && b<e)
    cout<<b<<endl;
if (c>a && c<b && c<d && c<e)
    cout<<c<<endl;
if (d>a && d<b && d<c && d<e)
    cout <<d<<endl;
if (e>a && e<b && e<c && e<d)
cout <<e<<endl;
return 0;

}
```

When I enter `1 2 3 4 5` it prints the second minimum, but when I enter 
`5 4 3 2 1` Nothing will print on the screen. What am I doing wrong with this? Is there any other way to write my program?

Comment: Maybe using recursive function.

Comment: Why you don't want to use arrays or loops? Writing code like this you won't learn anything about programming.

Comment: Why in gods name would you not want to use a loop for this?

Comment: For such problem I would suggest using tree.

Comment: Because I am ordered not to use array or loops.

Comment: @AdamHussein As Avix points out, that doesn’t actually help you learn anything about programming. Unless you’re supposed to use recursion, this is an idiotic busywork assignment.

Comment: I would use priority queue (min heap), and return the second pop. However, I think that uses std::vector internally, so maybe not a valid answer. Are we allowed to use recursion? Intermediate variables?

Comment: One trick is to find the minimum number, and then do the same again but ignoring the first minimum number. This will give you the second minimum number. See my answer below.

Comment: Hopefully the instructor is pushing use of standard algorithms.

Comment: This assignment is NOT just stupid busywork.  It shows how to use an accumulator.
You always have two previous minimums.  Every time you encounter a new number, if it is lower than the highest of your two current minimums, replace it with the new number.  When you're done, you've accumulated the two minimums.  Be sure to understand if you're allowed to have two of the same value if your inputs have duplicate minimums, or if they must be strictly different.

Comment: [Wikipedia: Example problems solvable by one-pass algorithms:... Find the k largest or smallest elements, k given in advance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-pass_algorithm). How can it be not about programming? :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have with your logic is that you do not enforce yourself to print only 1 item, and at least one item.
By using the 'else' part of the if/else syntax, you will ensure that only one branch can ever be hit.  You can then follow this up with just an else at the end, as you know all other conditions are false.

Once you've done this, you'll see that you print the last value, (1) rather than the expected (4).  This is because your logic regarding how to find the 2nd lowest is wrong.  b>a is false for the case 5,4...

Note:
Every employed engineer, ever, would make this a loop in a std::vector / std::array, and I would suggest you point your teacher to this post because encouraging loops is a good thing rather than bad.

Something like

```
vector<int> data;
for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    data.push_back(t);
}
std::nth_element(data.begin(), data.begin()+1, data.end(), std::greater<int>());
cout << data[1];
```

Comment: Is it impossible to do it without loops or array?

Comment: @AdamHussein no, it's just much more typing that you need to do; and the less you type the clearer your code will be; thus less likely to have bugs.
For example - if you were to use an array, you would just sort & then return the 2nd from the end.  2 lines, with the intention really obvious.

Comment: How can I do that with only if statements?

Comment: @AdamHussein That's the joy of it, there's no if at all;  If you have to, then look at Mil's or giorashc's answer. The likelyhood of getting something typed wrong though is much higher.

Comment: @UKMonkey That wouldn’t be the best way to get the second element from an array. The best way would be to use [`std::nth_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element), which is linear instead of O(n log n).

Comment: @DanielH very true!  Didn't know that.  Updated

Comment: You don't need to `push_back` into the vector in a loop if you already have `int a, b, c, d, e`: `vector<int> data{ a, b, c, d, e };` does it for you

Comment: Your solution is not memory efficient. There is no need to store all elements in memory to find the answer. So I don't agree with 'every employed engineer' part. It is nice solution for 5 elements though.

Comment: @Serikov no, it's not as memory efficient as it could be, for just this; but how are you so sure that the other values aren't used later?

Comment: @UKMonkey My point is that storing elements is orthogonal to solving this problem. You can use efficient one-pass algorithm and still store elements in container of choise. It is not required by such algorithm but not forbidden. As a side note, original order of elements is lost after invoking std::nth_element, so reusing same container later may be troublesome in certain contexts (if original order maters latter).

Answer (score 3):

There are 120 possible permutations on 5 elements. Your code should output the correct number for all of them. So a fool-proof code would use 120 repetitions of a check, like the following:

```
if (a > b && b > c && c > d && d > e) // the order is a>b>c>d>e
    cout << d;
else if (a > b && b > c && c > e && e > d) // the order is a>b>c>e>d
    cout << e;
...
else if (e > d && d > c && c > a && e > b) // the order is e>d>c>a>b
    cout << a;
else // the order is e>d>c>b>a
    cout << b;
```

This is very long, inefficient and tricky code. If you do a typo in just one variable, it will output a wrong answer in some rare cases. Also, it doesn't handle the possibility of some inputs being equal.

---

If the number of inputs to a sorting algorithm is a known small constant, you can use an approach called [sorting networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network). This is a well-defined computer science problem, which has well-known optimal solutions for small numbers of inputs, and 5 certainly is small. An optimal sorting network for 5 inputs contains 9 comparators, and is described e.g. [here](http://www.angelfire.com/blog/ronz/Articles/999SortingNetworksReferen.html).

Since you don't need to sort the numbers, but only to know the second smallest input, you can reduce the size of the network further, to 7 comparators.

The full sorting network (without the reduction from 9 to 7) translated to C++:

```
if (b < c)
    swap(b, c);
if (d < e)
    swap(d, e);
if (b < d)
    swap(b, d);
if (a < c)
    swap(a, c);
if (c < e)
    swap(c, e);
if (a < d)
    swap(a, d);
if (a < b)
    swap(a, b);
if (c < d)
    swap(c, d);
if (b < c)
    swap(b, c);
// now the order is a ≥ b ≥ c ≥ d ≥ e
cout << d;
```

This code is also obscure - not obvious at all how and why it works - but at least it is small and in a sense optimal. Also, it's clear that it always prints something (so it fixes the original problem) and supports the case of partially equal inputs.

If you ever use such code in a larger project, you should document where you took it from, and test it. Fortunately, there are exactly 120 different possibilities (or 32, if you use the 
[zero-one principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Zero-one_principle)), so there is a way to prove that this code has no bugs.

Comment: Sorting networks, nice. I knew I had seen this before somewhere. I suspect the OP is just learning if statements, so this is overkill but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you. (Note that it might not be the best approach and you can minimize it with a function to calculate min and secondMin instead of the ugly copy paste of the logic but it will get you started:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
int a,b,c,d,e;
int min, secondMin;


cin>>a>>b;

min = a < b ? a : b;
secondMin = a < b ? b : a;

cin>>c;

if (c < min)
{
    secondMin = min;
    min = c;
}
else if (c < secondMin)
{
    secondMin = c;
}

cin>>d;

if (d < min)
{
    secondMin = min;
    min = d;
}
else if (c < secondMin)
{
    secondMin = d;
}

cin>>e;

if (e < min)
{
    secondMin = min;
    min = e;
}
else if (e < secondMin)
{
    secondMin = e;
}

cout << "min = " << min << ", secondMin = " << secondMin << endl;

return 0;

}
```

if you have any questions feel free to ask in the comment

Comment: This is terrible oO

Comment: @YSC I didn't say it was the best approach and I am not here for making other people's homework. I gave a crude solution which he may on his own improve and minimize to an acceptable solution to whatever he needs to also note The OP clearly stated he cannot use loops and arrays

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <set>

std::set<int> values = { a, b, c, d, e }; // not an array.
int second_min = *std::next(values.begin(), 1); // not a loop
```

Comment: // it's not cheating :)

Answer (score 1):

What about a **recursive** and **more generic** approach?
**No arrays**, **no loops** and not limited to just 5 integers.

The following function `get_2nd_min()` keeps track of the two lowest integers read from `std::cin` a total of `count` times:

```
#include <climits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

int get_2nd_min(size_t count, int min = INT_MAX, int second_min = INT_MAX)
{
   if (!count)
      return second_min; // end of recursion

   // read next value from cin
   int value;
   std::cin >> value;

   // Does second_min need to be updated?
   if (value < second_min) {

     // Does min also need to be updated?
     if (value < min) {
        // new min found
        second_min = min; // move the so far min to second_min
        min = value; // update the new min
     } else {
        // value is lower than second_min but higher than min
        second_min = value; // new second_min found, update it
     }
   }
   // perform recursion
   return get_2nd_min(count - 1, min, second_min);
}
```

---

In order to read 5 integers and obtain the 2nd lowest:

```
int second_min = get_2nd_min(5);
```

Comment: As I beginner I didn't understand your answer. Is there any other way just like my code: cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e; then do statements to figure the second minimum number.

Comment: @AdamHussein the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` correspond to the variable `value` for the respective 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th call to the function `get_2nd_min()`. But you are not limited to just 5 integers, you can set the number of integers to be read from `std::cin` by means of the `count` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
In this solution I'm using the *min* function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int minDifferentFromFirstMin(int x, int y, int firstMin) {
    if(x < y) {
        if(x != firstMin) {
            return x;
        }
        else {
            return y;
         }
    }

    if(y < x) {
        if(y != firstMin) {
            return y;
        }
        else {
            return x;
         }
    }
    //if x & y are equals, return one of them
    return x;
}

int main () {
 int a,b,c,d,e;
 int iter11, iter12, iter13;
 int iter21, iter22, iter23;
 int firstMinimum, secondMinimum;
 cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;

 //iteration 1: find the first minimum
 iter11 = min(a, b);
 iter12 = min(c, d);
 iter13 = min(iter11, iter12);
 firstMinimum = min(iter13, e);

 //iteration 2: find the second minimum
 iter21 = minDifferentFromFirstMin(a, b, firstMinimum);
 iter22 = minDifferentFromFirstMin(c, d, firstMinimum);
 iter23 = minDifferentFromFirstMin(iter21, iter22, firstMinimum);
 secondMinimum = minDifferentFromFirstMin(iter23, e, firstMinimum);

 cout<<secondMinimum<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I added a new solution that works with all cases and simple to understand without using loops and arrays

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to first find the minimum number, `min` and then find the smallest value that isn't `min`. To do this first find the minimum value:

```
int min = std::min(a, std::min(b, std::min(c, std::min(d, e))));
```

Now we need to do the same again, but ignoring `min`. We can do this using a function called `triMin` which takes 3 values and discards any value that is the minimum:

```
int triMin(int currentMin, int left, int right)
{
    if(currentMin == left) return right;
    if(currentMin == right) return left;

    return std::min(left, right);
}
```

You can now combine them to get the answer:

```
int a = 5, b = 4, c = 3, d = 2, e = 1;

int min = std::min(a, std::min(b, std::min(c, std::min(d, e))));
int min2 = triMin(min, a, triMin(min, b, triMin(min, c, triMin(min, d, e))));

std::cout << "Second min = " << min2 << std::endl;
```

This prints `2`

Answer (score 0):

This task can be fulfilled using [one-pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-pass_algorithm) algorithm. There is no need to use any collections (arrays, sets or anything).
This one-pass algorithm is memory efficient - it does not require storing all elements in collection (and wasting memory) and will work even with large number of elements when other solutions fail with out of memory.
General idea of this algorithm is like this:

- take each number in order
- you need two variables to store `minimum` and `second minimum` numbers from all already seen numbers.
- when you get number you need to test it with current `minumum` to find if it is new minimum number.

  - if it is store it as `minimum`, store old minimum in `second minimum`number
- otherwise check if it is less than `second minimum` number.

  - if it is store it as `second minimum` number.
- now `second minimum` number contains answer for all already seen numbers.
- repeat while there numbers that was not seen.

After investigating all numbers `second minimum` contain the answer.
Here is implementation with c++17 ([link to wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/m8PJj2l1RMIhCsO4)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;

    // you can find second minimal number while going through each number once
    auto find_current_answer = [minimum = std::optional<int>{}, next_to_minimum = std::optional<int>{}](int next) mutable {
        // when receiving next number
        // 1. check if it is new minimum
        if (!minimum || minimum > next) {
            // move values like this: next_to_minimum <- minimum <- next
            next_to_minimum = std::exchange(minimum, next);
        }
        // 2. else check if it is new next_to_minimum
        else if (!next_to_minimum || next_to_minimum > next) {
            next_to_minimum = next;
        }
        // 3. return current answer
        return next_to_minimum;
    };

    // repeat as much as you like
    find_current_answer(a);
    find_current_answer(b);
    find_current_answer(c);
    find_current_answer(d);
    // store answer that is interesting to you
    auto result = find_current_answer(e);

    // if it has value - it is the answer
    if (result) {
        std::cout << "Answer: " << *result << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Not enough numbers!\n";
    }
}
```